# squid3: inject js into every visitet http site

Tags: xss, html

I own a squid3 proxy on a vps.
I can connect from my pc to the proxy, and can surf over the proxy's ip adress.

Is it possible to inject a simple 
    alert('unsafe connection')
into every http html site?